# Convert daily data into month and plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a `data.frame` including a daily date and a counter I made for each day in Excel before extracting to RStudio:

```
$ Date: Date, format: "2014-12-20" "2013-06-16"
$ Count: num  1 1
```

I have daily data from 2013-2016. I want to plot and analyze the data monthly.
Lets say I want to plot every count of all the months in 2013. How do I sum and plot the data?

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be great if you could include sample data to your post.

But you will be looking at doing something like this:

First, make sure your dates are parsed as, well, dates, with something resembling:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then you can use `cut`'s `breaks` methods, which takes a `"months` argument. For example:

```
cut(df$Year, breaks = "months")
```

[More on working with dates](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)

---

Edit after following question:

```
# make sure dates are parsed properly
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

# add a 'Monthly' column with month breaks
df$Monthly <- as.Date(cut(df$Year, breaks = "months"))

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(Monthly, Counter)) +
       stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "bar") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the following data:

> str(Data)
'data.frame': 31142 obs. of  2 variables:

 $ Date  : Date, format: "2014-12-20" "2013-06-16" "2014-03-17" 

 $ Counter: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ..

So the dates are allready parsed as dates and my counter is numeric. So how do I plot each monthly sum of lets say year 2013?

Comment: @Johnsen2013 see updated answer. Mark as solved once you're happy.